# Django Forms: Why doesn't boolean field work as I expect it?

Tags: django-forms

I have a form:

```
class myForm(forms.Form):        
     myBoolField = forms.BooleanField(
        label='myLabel', 
        required=True,
    )
```

Here is the corresponding template:

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <a class="btn" href="{{ secondary_action_url }}">{{ secondary_action_text }}</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

When Django renders this template myField shows up as an empty checkbox. 
If I check the box, hitting the submit button yields "True" for the cleaned value of myField.
However, If I leave the box empty and hit the submit button, instead of getting "False", I get None. That's not at all what I want. I want this check box to return True or False.

What do I do to make it work like I want (and expect)? Is my expectation that a Required Boolean field returns True or False misplaced?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class myForm(forms.Form):        
     myBoolField = forms.BooleanField(
        label='myLabel', 
        required=False,
        initial=False
     )
```

this prevents any further error, if you don't want to go deeper into this subject

*edit after edit after edit*: by marking required=True, you explicitly request an input from the user. by default, an unchecked checkbox doesn't get submitted (that's where the None value comes from) and your validation would fail everytime, because of the required.

Comment: This gives the following error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'

Comment: Are you sure? I tried that too. The syntax error goes away. But when the box is unchecked, it still returns null for that field.

I even added the function below to co-erce the cleaned value of myBoolField to True/False, and I still see it coming out as None. 

    def clean_myBoolField(self):
        myBoolField= self.cleaned_data['myBoolField']
        return myBoolField == True

Comment: d'uh, my bad again. I'll try to explain a little bit, give me a couple of mins :)

Comment: Thanks for this -  is there a nice way to do this for many booleanFields - or even All booleanFields in a form without writing a line for each one ?